# NFC Apps doesn´t start with the new Android 2.3.3 version for the Nexus S anymore

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s

Google released Android 2.3.3 for Nexus S [Update Tutorial](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/02/24/google-releases-android-2-3-3-update-zip-for-nexus-one-and-nexus-s/).
After installing Android 2.3.3 on my Nexus S, NFC Apps doesn´t start anymore, who started automatically with version 2.3.2. 
Normally the NFC Apps from the Android Market and my own Apps did start, when a NFC Tag was collected -> so the problem is not in the sorucecode,
but in the new Android Version. Has somebody figured out, how I can change my apps or the system to run them under Version 2.3.3?
I think this would help any developer, who wants to build some NFC Apps or has already built some NFC Apps.

Best regards

Alexander

Answer (score 2):

Google introduced an improved intent structure or "Tag Dispatch System" for NFC in 2.3.3. See [Near Field Communication](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html)

You can register your NFC intents in the manifest as before, but you have new options based on the new 'tech' types available, where you specify the tag technologies you'd like to handle.

The new foreground dispatch system also allows you to intercept the intents in your application when it is running and in the foreground. For me, this helped improve the user experience considerably!